# Fermat's theorem (stationary points) of higher dimensions

Tags: real-analysis

Look at this page and the Proof part,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_%28stationary_points%29

How to change the proof 2 into a proof of higher dimensions or can you give a proof of Fermat's theorem of higher dimensions?

Comment: Can't you just apply the one variable case in every direction $v$, deduce all partials $\partial_v$ vanish, hence $df$ is the 0 transformation?

Comment: @uncookedfalcon: But how about $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: To clarify, I need to prove this:
Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Prove that if $a$ is a local maximum point for $f$, then either $f$ is differentiable at $x=a$ with $Df(a)=0$ or $f$ is not differentiable at $a$.